# What is the Maven 'site' dependency type?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am familiar with type 'jar' and 'bundle' however I'm adding a dependency for Guava right now and where you used to be able to choose between types 'bundle' or 'jar' now you can choose 'bundle' or 'jar, site'. What is site?

Comment: New types can be defined by plugins that set extensions to true. Additional information may help answer your question. Do you have a link or dependency code snippet that you can post?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but will try and answer. Here is the XML that eclipse inserts for the dependency when I select the 'jar, site' option.


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.1</version>
    <classifier>site</classifier>
</dependency>

So it looks like site is a classifier rather than a 'type' which could help explain why I had trouble finding any information specific to it.

Comment: Though with that added knowlege I still haven't found an answer that made me feel like I could post an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site.jar is a result of this goal:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/jar-mojo.html

You are not supposed to use `site` as your project dependency, it doesn't even contain .class files. It contains your `project site` files e.g. html, images, css, etc. The same reason as why you shouldn't use `javadoc` and `sources` in your project dependencies even though they are available.

Comment: Thanks that adds a bit more to the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Classifier is used to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in content or to add secondary artifacts like javadoc to the main artifact. Its arbitrary and optional and if used its appended after the version number.

Comment: Thanks. That part I managed to glean from the Maven docs. I'm trying to find a little more specific information on site specifically to figure out if that's the one I should use or if I should use the 'bundle' one. I'm starting to assume that it's one of those things which refers to another maven plugin and thus is plugin specific or something.

Comment: The documentation from the Guava website where the artifact is made available would probably be your best bet in determining why they used it. When I was looking at the Guava website I did not see any classifier use.